# How to Resolve Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content & Leverage browser caching in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pagespeed

I am working on one of website but due to some reasons I'm having low Page Speed Score on Google Insight. Please Help me for following recommendations.

1.Leverage browser caching
2.Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
[Google Insight ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCDru.png)

Comment: Please help me. I want to complete this assignment soon.